# Function to make a redirect work in WordPress for ALL permalinks in a specific class

Tags: php, wordpress

On my WordPress site https://buildingsurveyorsgroup.com.au/forums/forum/building-surveyors-group-forum/ I have a function that allows a redirect if not logged in. But it only works for one link out of several with the same class.

I have got this function at the moment

function my_redirect() {

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    if ($current_url == 'a.bbp-topic-permalink') {
        wp_redirect('https://buildingsurveyorsgroup.com.au/register/');
    }
}
```

}

It works, but it only works for the first permalink that the class is attached too. Is there an code I could add the make it work for every permalink in the same class?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code. Where have you researched? Show us some effort.

Comment: I have been trying for a few hours, I am still new to programming. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this on the top of your codes:

```
if(!get_current_user_id()) header('location: http://google.co.id');
```

or if you want to spesific category, use this

```
if(the_category_ID() == $your_restricted_id) {
   if(!get_current_user_id()) header('location: http://google.co.id');
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your reply. Is it possible to use a class instead of category_ID? my permalink/s has a specific class attached to them.

Comment: sorry, what class do you mean? do you mean this class? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_class/ if yes, sure you can just use if(get_post_class...

Comment: My permalinks class is .bbp-topic-permalink, would it be possible to define the permalink I want to redirect in the function using that class?

Comment: do you mean you want to use the URL for the condition? then you can just grab the current URL, then use it like if($current_url=='../bbp-topic-permalik') to replace the the_category_ID() i mentioned above

Comment: Thats is!, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional statement around the link declaration if I am understating your question right. `if (is_user_logged_in()){print your link here}`

Comment: Thanks Niel!, I sorted the function here

function my_redirect() {

 if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
  if ($current_url == 'a.bbp-topic-permalink') {
   wp_redirect('https://buildingsurveyorsgroup.com.au/register/');
   exit;
  }
 }
}


But it only works with one link on the page. The others seem to stay there same, do I need to add something to the function to make it work with all the links in the same .class?